# multi-threading member functions c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, stl, member-functions

So I am trying to multithread the dot product computation between two matrix objects in a "library" I'm writing. here is the code of interest

```
double mat_cont::dot_t( mat_cont & other, const int offset,  \
const int upper_lim)

{
    double local_sum = 0;   
    for (int i = offset; i < upper_lim+offset; ++i)
        local_sum+=(this->mat[i] + other.mat[i]);

    return local_sum;
}


double mat_cont::dot( mat_cont & other){

    future<double> threads[3];
    int part = (int)(dim * dim) / (int)4;

    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i){
        threads[i-1] = 
            async (std::launch::async,&mat_cont::dot_t, 
                  other, part*i, (i+1)*part);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < part; ++i)
        sum+=(this->mat[i] + other.mat[i]);

    for(int i = 1; i < 3; ++i)
        sum+=threads[i].get();
    return sum;
    }
```

and this compilation error is thrown

```
error: no matching function for call to 'async'
             threads[i-1] = async (std::launch::async,&mat_cont::dot_t, other, part*i, (i+1)*part);
                            ^~~~~ 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/future:2337:1: 
note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Fp = double (mat_cont::*)(mat_cont &, int, int), _Args =
  <mat_cont &, int, int>]: no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::__invoke_of<double (mat_cont::*)(mat_cont &, int, int), mat_cont, int, int>'async(launch __policy, _Fp&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
```

I'm wondering if I can multithread this part, or if I need to pass both of these objects into a friend function for multithreading. I've been trying to debug this for 2 hours now, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat_cont::dot_t` is a non-static member function, so it needs a `this` object to work on.

The easiest way to deal with that is to use a lambda that captures the `this` pointer.  Then you can call `dot_t` exactly like you would in any other member function:

```
threads[i-1] = std::async(std::launch::async,
                          [this, i, part, &other]() {
                              return dot_t(other, part*i, (i+1)*part);
                          });
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1552bdc1d80ad10a)

Comment: this ended up working by the way. Interesting finally seeing a use case for lambdas; are there any other lambda use cases?

Answer (score 1):

`dot_t` is member function of `mat_cont` which takes 3 parameters, so there is one missing element in the call of `async` function - `this` pointer should be passed as third paremeter of the call

```
threads[i-1] = async (std::launch::async,&mat_cont::dot_t, this, std::ref(other), part*i, (i+1)*part);
```

Comment: As "first" of the three parameters, not "third"

Comment: I actually tried that and it threw a different error, sadly enough.  I thought it would work that way too

Comment: @MihaylA.A `dot_t` is called on `this` pointer, `this` is third parameter of `async` call, first paremetr of `dot_t` is `ref(other)`.

Comment: I mean `this` is always the first, hidden, parameter.